# VirtualHost Alias loads / redirects with "/myapp/" but errors without slash "/myapp"

Tags: virtualhost

I have a VirtualHost Alias path that loads / redirects with "/myapp/" but not "/myapp".

My sever info:

```
OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)
Kernel: Linux 3.10.*
```

My /etc/httpd/conf.d/main.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /myapp /m009/www/myapp-source
    <Directory /m009/www/myapp-source >
       Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to mydomain.com/myapp/ (note the extra slash), I get:

```
Here's the app!
```

If I go to mydomain.com/myapp (no extra slash), I get:

```
 - takes a long time to load
 - redirects to mydomain:9080/myapp
 - says "site can’t be reached"
```

Comment: I think you should use static path. And please set DocumentRoot in your config

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the correct answer as I do not know all the information.

Are you running an app on port 9080. Could it help to put `ProxyPass /myapp !` to the virtualHost?

Sorry if not.

Answer (score 0):

Alias is for exactly matching a path, so you have three options:

1. Add a second Alias statement with a trailing slash.  This could be bad because you'll have multiple paths to the same resource. e.g. `Alias /myapp/ /m009/www/myapp-source`
2. Use AliasMatch to match the path with or without a trailing slash.  e.g. 
   `AliasMatch "/myapp/?" "/m009/www/myapp-source"`
3. [Recommended] Rewrite requests to remove a trailing slash.  Beware that this could cause a loop depending on how your Apache installation is set up.  Check if DirectorySlash is on or off first.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]

    Alias /myapp /m009/www/myapp-source

    <Directory /m009/www/myapp-source >
       Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```